# Support for custom compression algorithms in HBase / Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, compression, hbase

I am experimenting with compression on Hadoop/HBase and would like to add my own compression routine for block compression in HBase. I see that HBase has support for the following types of compression out of the box:

```
create 'mytable', {NAME=>'colfam:', COMPRESSION=>'gz'}
```

where 'gz' can be replaced with 'lzo' (liv-zempel), 'snappy', or 'none'.

My question, is it possible to write your own compression routine/codec and use it above for your column families? Something like:

```
create 'mytable', {NAME=>'colfam:', COMPRESSION=>'myCompressionRoutine'}
```

What would be required to do something like this?

I also noticed a strange comment in some of the Java docs. The following comment was found here: https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/hfile/Compression.Algorithm.html

*"Compression algorithms. The ordinal of these cannot change or else you risk breaking all existing HFiles out there. Even the ones that are not compressed! (They use the NONE algorithm)"*